# How do we convert jQuery $('div#item').html() in VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert jQuery method to VanillaJS

`$('div#item').html()`

can convert `.html()` using `innerHTML`. But have the issue with `$('div#item')`. I used `document.getElementById('div#item').innerHTML` It's not working for me. Someone please suggest any better solution.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('item').innerHTML`

Comment: `document.querySelector('div#item')`

Comment: 1. The most trivial amount of research would surely have given you your answer. 2. It's not "vanilla JS," it's using the DOM ([specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)) instead of jQuery. jQuery isn't a language. The language, in *both* cases, is JavaScript.

Comment: Try http://youmightnotneedjquery.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the actual id of the element you want to acess

```
document.getElementById('item').innerHTML
```

Comment: Small correction: this code does not work exactly in the same way as jQuery `$("div#item")` does. If the OP wants to get inner HTML of element with name `item` only if it is `div`, then this code will not make this "div" check. However, it is unlikely.

Comment: it is not checking for name but for id and anyways there should not be multiple elements with same id.

Comment: I mean, for HTML `<p id="item">hello world</p>` jQuery code provided by OP returns `undefined`, `querySelector` throws error and your code returns `hello world`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev An id should be unique, so specifying that the #id is linked to a div should not be necessery or your html is bad

Comment: @user5014677 `item` is unique ID in my HTML, as you can see :) It is just related to another HTML tag. It is all about "give div with ID item" vs "give any element with ID item".

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Problem is not your html but what you said. It doesn't make sense. If you have to check the tag for and id it just means that your design is false.

Comment: @user5014677 I did not tell that I check the tag. I said that the OP asked to convert his jQuery code into the same JavaScript analogue. This code is not an analogue, but makes sense because probability of such case is very low. However, it is possible - ID is not guaranteed to be unique across different pages, so it is technically possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.getElementById('item')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use vanilla JS for this task

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#item')[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: There's no point in building the list just to take the first element. To get just the first matching element, use `querySelector`.

Comment: Yes no need to add querySelectorAll for first element.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
console.log (document.querySelector('div#item').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="item">ololo</div>
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: this might not working in two cases: 1. you have not div with id=item at the execution moment. 2. somewhere you crush DOM link structure for example using element.html('<div id="imet">') instead of append etc.

Comment: I did a snippet for you here. it is working.